# Python MySQL: Select with default value

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have a database created from

```
CREATE TABLE `ip` (
  `idip` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip` decimal(45,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mask` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idip`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ip_UNIQUE` (`ip`)
)
```

And I've made some insertions into this table

But when I try to execute on python:

```
sql = "select idip from ip where ip=%s and mask=%s" % (long(next_hop), 'DEFAULT')
cursor.execute(sql)
idnext_hop = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

I get the following error:

```
    Inserting routes into table routes (1/377)...('insere_tabela_routes: Error on insertion at table routes, - SQL: ', 'select idip from ip where ip=0 and mask=DEFAULT')
1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

Does anyone have a clue on what is the problem?

Comment: First of all, I hope the values you are passing aren't user-supplied because that's a SQL injection just waiting to happen. Second, have you tried printing the actual `sql` string value for debugging purposes? What does it say (verbatim)? Instead, don't use python string substitution, let it do that for you.

Comment: Yes, printing sql is inside the error message 'select idip from ip where ip=0 and mask=DEFAULT'

I am pretty noob at sql so I'm still trying to understand how to do this selection with 2 values, once doing so with only one value works pretty well

Comment: The method proposed by Gordon below is best, should work.

Comment: Didn't work at all, now I get a different error message "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement"

Comment: What MySQL library are you using? I suspect it's an odd one that does not use question marks for parameterized/sanitized queries. That would be important to know to help you with this.

Comment: I am using mysql.connector

Comment: that's why. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`mysql.connector` uses `%s` instead of `?` as the parameter marker](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html), but you are circumventing it by using Python string formatting. Try this:

```
sql = "select idip from ip where ip=%s and mask=%s"
cursor.execute(sql, (long(next_hop), 'DEFAULT'))
idnext_hop = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

Comment: That was exactly the solution. Thank you both, Arthur Dent and Gordon Linoff

Comment: @bruna if this helped you, please consider upvoting and marking as the solution / accepted answer. Otherwise future visitors of this question won't know which answer(s) helped and are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are munging the query string with parameters, rather than passing them in as, well, parameters.  The code should look like this:

```
sql = "select idip from ip where ip = ? and mask = ?"
cursor.execute(sql, (long(next_hop), 'DEFAULT'))
idnext_hop = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

In other words, you want the query engine to do the substitution into the query.  You don't want Python to do the substitution into the query string.

Comment: When trying that, I get the error message: "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement"

Comment: @bruna . .. That's interesting.  There are two parameters inthe query and two in the list.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it turns out OP is using `mysql.connector`, which does use `%s` as the parameter marker, but OP was trying to use python string formatting instead of letting cursor/query do the safe parameterized substitution. Unfortunately OP did not include this in original question - only learned it from [a comment.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50381839/python-mysql-select-with-default-value/50382139#comment87780078_50381839). In case you want to edit.